# Marginnote with geometry package

Tags: margins, memoir, marginpar, double-sided, geometry

In my document i'm using the packages *geometry* and *marginnote*.
The problem ist the following:
If I use a newgeometry, the marginnote will stay on odd pages at same horizontaly position as by the original geometry.

The following minimal example should give the bad output:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{twoside,paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, top=35mm,
bottom=40mm, left=35mm, right=50mm, marginparsep=3mm,  marginparwidth=40mm}
\savegeometry{inhalt}

\begin{document}

%first page
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
\marginnote{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
}

%second page
\clearpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
\marginnote{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
}

%third page
%right margin will set on 90 mm
\newgeometry{top=35mm,  bottom=40mm, left=35mm, right=90mm,
marginparsep=3mm,  marginparwidth=40mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
\marginnote{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
}

%fourth page
\clearpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
\marginnote{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua.%
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `marginnote` package is compatible with `memoir`, which provides its own methods for various sorts of floating and non-floating notes.  Your document works fine if you remove `\usepackage{marginnote}` and replace all the `\marginnote` commands with `\sidebar`.